# OpenLayers & GeoServer: How to force TILEMATRIX prefix

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wmts

I set up a WMTS in GeoServer-GWC. I generated the tiles with the gridset EPSG:4326.

In my OpenLayers client, I have following configuration

```
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        opacity: 0.7
      }),
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        opacity: 0.7,
        source: new ol.source.WMTS({
          url: 'https://geoserver.***.com.au/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts',
          layer: 'layer',
          matrixSet: 'EPSG:4326',
          format: 'image/png',
          projection: projection,
          tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
            origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
            resolutions: resolutions,
            matrixIds: matrixIds
          }),
          style: 'default',
          wrapX: true
        })
      })
    ],
```

No tiles are displayed in the browser and the requests fails as they look like this:

```
https://geoserver.***.com.au/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?layer=layer&style=default&tilematrixset=EPSG:4326&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image/png&TileMatrix=6&TileCol=58&TileRow=18
```

Notice the **TileMatrix parameters**. It should be **EPSG:4326:5** instead of just **5**.

Any clue where I have to configure the prefix?

Comment: what is in matrixIds? - I think that is where that comes from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the way matrixIds are displayed. In the code,

```
matrixIds[z] = 'EPSG:4326:' + z;
```